# Is there a way to safely redeclare a symbol?

Tags: raku

I often find myself experimenting in the REPL and I will say something like:

`subset Bar of Int where * %% 57;`

Then I play around with checks on the `Bar`-ness for things for a bit.

Everything is happy, until I realize that I want to change the definition of `Bar`.

If I just redefine `Bar`, I get a `Redeclaration of symbol` exception.

I tried using `MONKEY-TYPING` and `augment` like this:

```
use MONKEY-TYPING;
augment subset Bar of Int where * %% 37;
```

But that netted me the same error.

Why do I want this?  So I can iterate on my subset (or class, or other symbol) definitions, while reusing the tests I've already typed that are in my history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the REPL does part of its magic by `EVAL`-ing each new input in a new nested lexical scope. So, if you declare things with `my` then you can shadow them with declarations entered later:

```
my subset Bar of Int where * %% 57;
sub take-Bar(Bar $n) { say "$n is Bar" }
take-Bar 57;

my subset Bar of Int where * %% 42;
sub take-Bar(Bar $n) { say "$n is Bar" }
take-Bar 42;
```

If you omit `my`, then for `subset` and `class` declarations, `our` will be used, and since `our` is actually `my` + adding the symbol to the enclosing package...; turns out if you delete the symbol from the package, you can then shadow it again later:

```
subset Bar of Int where * %% 57;
GLOBAL::<Bar>:delete;
subset Bar of Int where * %% 42;
42 ~~ Bar;
```

NOTE: These results are just from my experiments in the REPL. I'm not sure if there are other unknown side effects.

Answer (score 8):

The `REPL` has its shortcomings.  It is an elaborate construction of `EVAL` statements that try to work together.  Sometimes that doesn't work out.

I guess the best we could do, is to introduce a REPL command that would make it forget everything it has done before.  Patches welcome! :-)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I was on the right track with `use MONKEY-TYPING` and `augment` but they don't work properly in the REPL(yet?) because it needs a lot of magic and duck tape.

Comment: AFAIK, you can only use augment to *add* stuff to a class.  What you are trying to do is *replace* a *subset*.

Comment: @daotoad To replace, you can use `supersede`, but I believe at the present time that remains unimplemented.

Comment: Supersede is still unimplemented, but that would only work on an installed module level anyway.  The supersede function should allow a module to indicate it should be loaded instead of another module / version.  It is therefore a hint to the CompUnitRepo when asked if it can provide a given module.